# setTimeout() won't execute

Tags: javascript

I have two examples using `setTimeout().` This one works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization','1',{packages:['table']});
    function start() {
            setTimeout(ShowClipboardContent, 2000);
    }

    function ShowClipboardContent() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(window.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('div'));
    table.draw(data,{showRowNumber: true});
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='start();'>Show text data in clipboard</button>
    <div id='div'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization','1',{packages:['table']});
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //runs powershell and copies output onto clipboard
        function powershell(t) {
            //object that will execute powershell
            var run = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
            //breaks the list of servers into array
            var servers = t.textarea.value.split('\n');
            //script that powershell will run
            var script = 'some powershell command';
            //path to powershell.exe
            var program = 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe';
            //putting it all together
            run.ShellExecute(program,script,'','open','1');
            setTimeout(drawTable, 10000);
        }

        //draws data table using data from clipboard
        function drawTable() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(window.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
            table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='form'>
        <form>
            Enter name(s):<br />
            <textarea id='textarea' style='width:20%; height:500px;'></textarea><br />
            <button onclick='powershell(this.form)'>Query</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='table'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to reiterate: the problem is that `setTimeout()` won't work on the second code but works on the first one and I would like to know why because I see no difference.

Comment: You are sure the problem is the `setTimeout`, and not maybe all the ActiveX stuff?

Comment: Clearly, the code *prior* to the `setTimeout` call in `powershell` is failing, probably because no modern browser supports arbitrary `ActiveXObject` calls anymore. Look in your web console for errors, step through the code in the debugger built into your browser, etc.

Comment: Open up your console (for example, cmd+opt+J on Mac and Chrome) and copy and paste the error here please.

Comment: Are you sure that the `ActiveXObject` isn't causing this to not work, as it looks like your `ActiveXObject` isn't actually defined causing your code to fail.

Comment: Your second script won't work on any browser other than IE

Comment: @Chris: ActiveX is a proprietary technology in IE.

Comment: Well, I am running on IE11 and I have opened the developer tools and nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a 
`console.log(drawTable);`
just before your timeout. if it returns 'function', it'a good, your timeout will be ok. if not return anything, your activeX script should break the code

Comment: Console.log() doesn't work at all for my IE11, and I mean doesn't work as nothing appears. I've tried 'Hello World', with nothing else on the page.